# LEDs buzzing even with dimmer removed

Tags: wiring, lighting, led

There are a lot of questions about LED light bulbs buzzing on dimmers but mine is the opposite.

I replaced my bulbs with WiZ LEDs which have dimming built in to their app. So they specifically recommend removing dimming switches and replacing with a regular switch.

So I removed the dimmer switch (which had 3 wires coming from it but only 2 actually connected, the 3rd was just capped off). I replaced it with a regular switch with no dimming. Both wires are still being used.

But the LEDs still make a buzzing sound when they are turned on. The same LEDs in a different room don’t buzz (that room never had a dimming switch to begin with)

What could be causing this? Is it possible the fixture still has “dimming” even if the dimmer switch has been replaced with a regular switch? Was I supposed to only connect 1 wire to the switch?

Comment: Typically the 3 wires on a dimmer either "hot supply", "hot lamp" and "ground", or instead of ground a 3-way control line that isn't used in single-switch configuration.  A switch with a metal yoke will automagically pick up ground from the steel junction box (if it is steel).

Comment: Are the buzzing vs not-buzzing LEDs the same brand (same batch)? Since LEDs don't like house AC, there is a power module in each to convert AC to what the LEDs want. Cheaper ones may well buzz...

Comment: Have you swapped the two leds ?

Comment: Which two leds should he have swapped, @RohitGupta?

Comment: @FreeMan - The OP has them in two rooms and one of them does not buzz.

Comment: The ones that don’t buzz are the same brand but different style bulb. I tried moving the buzzing one to another room which never had a dimming switch and it still buzzes there. So maybe the bulb itself just makes noise? Is that normal? They are WiZ brand

Comment: Sounds like maybe just a bad bulb.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like it is your actual light fixture causing it to buzz if the same LED bulb is inserted into another light fixture and it does not create the buzzing sound.

Comment: Links die - Stack Exchange answers should not rely on external sources. Edit the relevant details into your answer.